# CursorLoader, unsubscribe from ContentProvider notifications

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I'm using a `CursorLoader` to query a `ContentProvider` to populate a `ListView`, with the following code (wrapped in a `LoaderManager`):

```
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                Provider.CONTENT_SOME_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                null,
                null);
```

And an `AsyncQueryHandler` to update `SOME_VALUE` for a given `_id` triggered on click on a `CheckBox` placed on every single entry of the `ListView`

```
final AsyncQueryHandler handler = new AsyncQueryHandler(contentResolver) {};
final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(Table.SOME_COLUMN, someValue);
final Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Provider.CONTENT_SOME_URI, String.valueOf(someId));
handler.startUpdate(0,
       null,
       uri,
       values,
       null,
       null);
```

Finally, in my ContentProvider, I've something like that:

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ...){
    ... // update stuff
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
}
```

The problem is the following:

When I check a single item, this item is updated, notifyChange tells `CursorLoader` to reload, and the whole list is reloaded, causing the list to scroll top, animations to stop, each time a `CheckBox` is checked...

Don't know what to do...

Thanks!

Comment: If the whole list is reloading, then your `onLoadFinished` is doing something wrong. Can you include that code?

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, I was calling setListAdapter within onLoadFinished, working with swapCursor() instead, awesome!
Maybe you could create an answer, so I can close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setListAdapter`, that causes the list to completely wipe out its data and regenerate the whole list. You should instead only call `swapCursor()` in your `onLoadFinished()` - this tells the adapter that the data has changed, but it will use the list element ids to reuse items, causing your list to remain, in your case, completely stable